# Is there a SSLv2 document?

Tags: tls

There is no rfc document about ssl version 2.0

Where can i find specification document of sslv2?

I'm curious about available ciphersuite(MD4)
, whether it use mac-then-encrypt or encrypt-then mac

Comment: I think this is the one: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-hickman-netscape-ssl-00

Answer (score 4):

First result in google is this:
http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/ssl/draft02.html